# Disable startup program in registry;

Tags: c#, startup, autorun

There are a lot of programs which manage startup application. They get some programs list and allow user to enable/disable program in startup.

I can get some program list from registry (like `HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run` and others)

How they perform enabling/disabling? If I delete registry key then this program will disappear from startup list.

How can I disable program from startup without deleting registry key? Is there some flag in registry key for it?

I don't have any code because I don't how I can do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you code anything to accomplish this?

Comment: No, i only can get startup programs from registry keys (HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run and others keys),but i don't know how to disable program without deleting registry entry or get program status (enabled or disabled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a program at startup like that:

```
    private void SetStartup()
    {
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        rk.SetValue("Notepad", "c:\windows\notepad.exe");
    }
```

Now if you want to remove it then just edit the path slightly.

```
    rk.SetValue("Notepad", "c:\windows\notepad.exe_");
```

Later on if you want to reset it, just remove the *underscore*.

Comment: So why is the question tagged with C# then?

Comment: You're not answering his question. He wants to do it programmatically.

Comment: OK guys. Cut me a slack. I have edited the answer. Thanks anyways.

Comment: That looks rather hacky... i think this is what you're looking for: https://superuser.com/questions/664641/where-are-disabled-autostart-programs-stored-somewhere-in-the-registry